# Cargo run using PyO3

Tags: rust, pyo3, maturin

I'm working on a rust/python package using PyO3 and its working great from python after I run `maturin develop`. I can import my rust code into Python and run my functions as I expect.

I would also like to still run my code from Rust though, and so when I run `cargo run`, I get the following errors:

```bash
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is are some simple instructions to replicate this:

### 1. Setup

```
# (replace string_sum with the desired package name)
$ mkdir string_sum
$ cd string_sum
$ python -m venv .env
$ source .env/bin/activate
$ pip install maturin
```

### 2. Initialize Package using `maturin`

```bash
maturin init
```

### 3. Add `main.rs` file

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

### 4. Run

```
cargo run
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the solution is similar to the reported error with `cargo test`, [here](https://pyo3.rs/v0.13.2/faq.html#i-cant-run-cargo-test-im-having-linker-issues-like-symbol-not-found-or-undefined-reference-to-_pyexc_systemerror):

```ini
[lib]
name = "lib"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

...

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.16.5"

[features]
extension-module = ["pyo3/extension-module"]
default = ["extension-module"]
```

and then if you run:

```bash
cargo run --no-default-features
```

It works as expected